# How likely is it to find primers sequences in already-trimmed reads?

Tags: sequence-alignment, sequence-analysis, phylogenetics, fastq, primer

So, I am analysing 18S amplicon data (fastq files) to be able to eventually investigate the taxa composition.

After removing primers (using `cutadapt`) from both R1 and R2 (assuming primers are found at the beginning of my sequences), I am still able to detect, apparently at random, a few reads that contain my primers (i.e. a part of the sequence matching the primer) in, again apparently random, positions.

I am able to detect almost all my primers (16 out of 24, both forward and reverse) in at least one sequence and I am wondering how common (or how weird) this is. I guess it is important to consider that my primers contains a few, i.e. from 1 to 3, wild-card bases that may match multiple other bases (apparently called [whobble bases](https://www.biosearchtech.com/support/faqs/custom-oligonucleotides-modifications/what-are-wobbles)), which makes it easier to match a random sequence (there are multiple possibilities for an actual match).

Problem is that the presence of primers in the sequences may affect downstream analyses (e.g. with DADA2 [they are very clear](https://benjjneb.github.io/dada2/tutorial_1_8.html) about the fact that primers have to be removed) in several ways and I was wondering if these sequences I am finding may be interfering somehow of if I can live with it.

Comment: The primers will be at the 3'-end of the reads. Make sure you check for them there.

Comment: @DevonRyan yes, that I know and that I did so no primers at 3'. I guess it just happens to find them inside the reads, as random matches, but I wasn't expecting that many actual matches. I guess it's statistics, then.

Comment: Interesting, have you tried to map a read with a sequence matching a primer to the reference, or even simply blasting it? Does the reference contain the "primer sequence"? ("" as we don't know if it's a homologous sequence or not)

Comment: @KamilSJaron apparently this is something that should not be happening and I'm trying to understand why it does.